# C#. How do I fill ListView fully? All Items and all Subitems

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

everyone. How do I fill ListView fully at once.
For example, I click some button and my LisView fills fully, all Items and all SubItems that I have.

Comment: There are at least 4 ListView controls in .NET: ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF and Silverlight all have their own ListView. Which of these are you using?

Comment: Well, you just populate the list view items and there they all are? I can't see a question here. If you care to post some code and explain why it doesn't meet you expectations, that would be a question.

Comment: I use Windows Forms, C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also confused by this when I started using `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` (I'm assuming that is the `ListView` you're referring to).

Essentially, each row in the ListView corresponds to a single `ListViewItem` in the `.Items` collection.  The text of the item appears in the *first* column of the ListView.  When the ListView is in details mode (`.View = View.Details`), then the `SubItems` collection is used, which is a property of *each* `ListViewItem`.

The pattern can be seen in the [example code for `ListView` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx):

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1",0);
item1.SubItems.Add("1");
item1.SubItems.Add("2");
item1.SubItems.Add("3");
ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2",1);
item2.SubItems.Add("4");
item2.SubItems.Add("5");
item2.SubItems.Add("6");
listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{item1,item2});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the .NET ListView?

You can change the View Property to 'Details' and that will show all items and subitems.

Comment: Thanx, I know, I've change it. But I need to FILL VALUES MY LISTVIEW.

Comment: @Daria Traditionally, repeating yourself in all-caps is among the poorer ways to encourage a helpful response. Are you having trouble looping through the items you want to place in the list and calling `ListView.Items.Add()` with each of them?

Comment: For example my listview has 5 columns and 10 rows, and I have 5 arrays with length = 10. so I need fill all 50 Items by one Button click with this arrays. I'm sorry if I'm not not entirely accurate, because I just learn English and maybe I can't work out right.

Answer (score 0):

The SubItems get populated from second column onwards, if the listview has columns. The first column is taken by the top level item.